# How to add action listeners to individual elements in a Tile Pane

Tags: java, javafx, actionlistener, flowpane

Is it possible to add action listeners to the indiviadual elements in a Tile or Flow Pane?

For example, in the example below, if a user clicked on an image, the the system would print out the location/ file path.

Thank You All.

```
public class FlowTileExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(30);

        //loading images
        Image[] im = new Image[8];
        im[0] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("facebook.png"));
        im[1] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("faviicon.png"));
        im[2] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("jquery-logo.png"));
        im[3] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("linkedin_32.png"));
        im[4] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("loading1.png"));
        im[5] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("twitter.png"));
        im[6] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("twitter_32.png"));
        im[7] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("wp.png"));

        VBox up = new VBox(20);
        Text text4flow = new Text("Images in FlowPane");
        text4flow.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
        text4flow.setUnderline(true);
        VBox.setMargin(text4flow, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        //creating Flow Pane
        FlowPane flowpane = new FlowPane();
        flowpane.setHgap(5);
        flowpane.setVgap(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            flowpane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(im[i]));
        }

        up.getChildren().addAll(text4flow, flowpane);

        VBox down = new VBox(20);
        Text text4tile = new Text("Images in TilePane");
        text4tile.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
        text4tile.setUnderline(true);
        VBox.setMargin(text4tile, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));

        //creating Tile Pane
        TilePane tilepane = new TilePane();
        tilepane.setHgap(5);
        flowpane.setVgap(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            tilepane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(im[i]));
        }
        down.getChildren().addAll(text4tile, tilepane);
        root.getChildren().addAll(up, down);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Flow And Tile Panes Example");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is yes.  The long answer would involve more context.  `ImageView` doesn't really have a "action listener" context, but it does have mouse and key input...

Comment: Thanks [@MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) for the reply. How could I go about it with the mouse and key input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some kind of handler to the `ImageView` instance, for example...

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(im[i]);
imageView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("Oh dear lord, they clicked me!?");
    }
});
```

Or you could create a generic handler...

```
EventHandler mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) t.getSource();
        System.out.println("You clicked " + imageView.getImage());
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(im[i]);
    imageView.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
    flowpane.getChildren().add(imageView);
}
```

For example...

You should take a closer look at [Handling JavaFX Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm) for more details

Comment: Thank you so much [@MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer). Let me study this. If I had enough points I'd up-vote you. I'll accept your answer later. Let me leave the question open for the time being. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to MadProgrammer, for the quick managing the custom data you can utilize node's `userData` property, instead of constructing your own data model. The userData can be used in different situations like attaching some context data with the related node:

```
VBox root = new VBox();
final Glow glow = new Glow();

EventHandler<MouseEvent> handlerMouseClicked = (MouseEvent t) -> {
    System.out.println("url = " + ((ImageView) t.getSource()).getUserData());
};

EventHandler<MouseEvent> handlerMouseEntered = (MouseEvent t) -> {
    ((ImageView) t.getSource()).setEffect(glow);
};

EventHandler<MouseEvent> handlerMouseExited = (MouseEvent t) -> {
    ((ImageView) t.getSource()).setEffect(null);
};

String[] imageNames = {"rere.png", "rere_1.png", "rere_2.png"};
for (String imageName : imageNames) {
    String url = getClass().getResource(imageName).toExternalForm();
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(url));
    iv.setUserData(url);
    iv.setOnMouseEntered(handlerMouseEntered);
    iv.setOnMouseExited(handlerMouseExited);
    iv.setOnMouseClicked(handlerMouseClicked);
    root.getChildren().add(iv);
}
```

Comment: You *could* do this; I've never really understood why you would though. You can just as easily use the reference to the data directly in the event handler: e.g. in the `onMouseClicked` handler do `System.out.println("url = " + url)`. (This implicitly passes the url to the anonymous event handler object, instead of keeping it in the userData property of the Node. The advantage is you maintain the type, instead of needing to downcast.)

Comment: Your point is right. However by saying "As an addition to MadProgrammer" I was trying to mention a common handler that can be set to all imageviews. Also my main purpose was to show userData that can be used in different situations like attaching some context data with the related node.